# Trying to import a list of words using csv (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

```
import csv, Tkinter

with open('most_common_words.csv') as csv_file: # Opens the file in a 'closure' so that when it's finished it's automatically closed"
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file) # Create a csv reader instance

    for row in csv_reader: # Read each line in the csv file into 'row' as a list
        print row[0] # Print the first item in the list
```

I'm trying to import this list of most common words using csv. It continues to give me the same error

```
for row in csv_reader: # Read each line in the csv file into 'row' as a list
Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

I've tried a couple different ways to do it as well, but they didn't work either. Any suggestions?

Also, where does this file need to be saved? Is it okay just being in the same folder as the program?

Comment: Can you show what your csv file looks like?

Comment: What happens if you do open the file in universal newline mode? What delimiter is used in your file? Which quote characters? What kind of newlines?

Comment: It is a simple list of words. When I open it up, it opens into Excel with one column and 500 rows of 500 different words.

Comment: I bet you're not in the US, then. European Excel versions expect a different CSV delimiter than US Excel versions, for example. Please show an excerpt of the file you're trying to open.

Comment: Hi, glad you solved your problem. But you shouldn't edit your question to show that - that's what the checkmark buttons are there for. You can mark one of the answers as accepted to show to others that that's the one that helped you most. (OK, in this case, there's only one answer yet, but still that checkmark is used to mark the question as answered). And if you came up with your own solution, you can answer your own question and accept that answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should always open a CSV file in binary mode (Python 2) or universal newline mode (Python 3). Also, make sure that the delimiters and quote characters are `,` and `"`, or you'll need to specify otherwise:

```
with open('most_common_words.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';', quotechar='"') # for EU CSV
```

You can save the file in the same folder as your program. If you don't, you can provide the correct path to `open()` as well. Be sure to use raw strings if you're on Windows, otherwise the backslashes may trick you: `open(r"C:\Python27\data\table.csv")`

Comment: Why should you always open in binary mode?  I've seen this before, but never saw an explanation as to why...

Comment: @SteveP.: Short answer: [Because the docs says so](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader). Long answer: Because the CSV fields might contain embedded newlines, and they aren't necessarily the same kind of newlines as the ones used to delimit the lines of the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a file with one column as you say here:

> It is a simple list of words. When I open it up, it opens into Excel
>   with one column and 500 rows of 500 different words.

If so, you don't need the csv module at all:

```
with open('most_common_words.csv') as f:
   rows = list(f)
```

Note in this case, each item of the list will have the newline appended to it, so if your file is:

```
apple
dog
cat
```

`rows` will be `['apple\n', 'dog\n', 'cat\n']`

If you want to strip the end of line, then you can do this:

```
with open('most_common_words.csv') as f:
    rows = list(i.rstrip() for i in f)
```